# Laravel Package Authentication

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel 4 web application where users can login and edit their profile.

I've created an API package that allows the user to login with their username/password and get a json dump of their profile.

Now, I don't want the API users to use their username/password but instead to use an app_id / app_key from another table in the database.

How to accomplish this with Laravel 4? It would be fantastic if I can create an Auth driver that works the same way `Auth:attempt()` would so I don't have to change any of my business logic, but I don't know how to inject a new Auth service provider that ONLY works inside of the API package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your Auth settings at where you want. You can create a filter in filters.php like that:

```
Route::filter('api_auth', function()
{
   Config::set('auth.table', 'api_table');
   // you can even change your model
   // Config::set('auth.model', 'Apiuser');
});
```

And use before any route in routes.php like that:

```
Route::get('user', array('before' => 'api_auth', function()
{
   // some stuff
}));
```

So that, you can use different settings and do what you want.

*BTW, I tried this method at Laravel 3, it worked. I looked docs of laravel 4, I couldn't see anything prevent this work.*